# How to make Flutter Stream Builder return seamlessly

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I have a little problem here where i have logged in with Google Auth using Firebase but everytime i tried to restart the app i expect the app will show the HomePage() without any problem, but i found that before it return, the app had like a bit seconds in LoginPage() before displaying HomePage(), is there any way to make it seamlessly

```
class AuthService extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthService({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return HomePage();
          } else {
            return LoginPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because for snapshot to reach `snapshot.hasData` state it takes time, and meanwhile else part is executed which is `LoginPage()`.

##### How to overcome this?

Try to wrap within `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active` which means once stream is connected then check the condition else return `CircularProgressIndicator`

##### Code:

```
   StreamBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return HomePage();
            } else {
              return LoginPage();
           }
         }
         return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
  );
```

Comment: this is one is just the same but ur code just replace a bit of second to displaying a circular indicator, i guess this is the best approach